# Align 3 divs. 2 of them width fixed width and the third auto

Tags: html, css

I want to align 3 divs. Two of them have fixed width and the right one with auto width to fill of the empty space at the right.

Any hint?

Here's my exemple:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; background-color:Red;">
    <div id="left" style="width:100px; height:400px; background-color: yellow; float:left; display:inline-block">
    </div>        

    <div id="center" style="width:600px; height:400px; background-color: blue; float:none; display:inline-block">
    </div>    

    <div class="right" style=" height:400px; width:auto;background-color: green; float:right; display:inline-block">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this:

**CSS:**

```
.fixed{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    float:left;
    background:green;
}

.fuild{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
}
div{
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">1</div>
<div class="fixed">2</div>
<div class="fuild">3</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AScBN/

Comment: Do you mean `fluid`? Or what is `fuild` supposed to mean?

Comment: @sandeep , i don't want to do this, but it's "right" not "write"

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
#div-1, #div-2 {width:100px;float:left}
#div-3 {margin-left:200px}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-1"></div>
<div id="div-2"></div>
<div id="div-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This only work if you want the third div with fix position, but if you want the second div with fluid with you need to make this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .right {
float:left;
width: 100px;
}
.right {
float: right;
}
.center {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
right: 100px;
}
```